# Translation ambiguity in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, translation

I am doing cross language search in solr for that purpose i am doing query translation from language A to Language B , These translations are based on bilingual dictionary . The problem i am currently facing is "For some words in query i have more than one translations ". Here i need to put correct word for translation. How can i resolve this translation ambiguity .

Here in this case we can not determine context of query because queries may be too short for that. Only one way i can see is probability occurrence of words.  Is there any way so that i can check probability of words occurring together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would call analyzing the probability of words appearing together a simplistic form of context, and I would think that in a query it would be highly error prone, and cause you to miss relevant results.  This is a very difficult problem with complete, contextful sentences.  Ambiguities in user-entered query strings you can expect to be unresolvably ambiguous, and so an attempt to resolve them, I believe, would make your search frustratingly unpredictable, and may even make some concepts difficult or impossible to search for.

My recommendation, for what it's worth, would be to search both alternative translations, using an implementation like a [SynonymFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html).

So if I were searching for the English word `"fine"`, in Spanish I might explode it out to the query `"multa fino sutil"`.

It probably makes sense to wrap these lists of synonyms in a [DisjunctionMaxQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html) to protect against hits on multiple translations of the same term influencing scoring more than they should.  So if searching for

- "fine point"

I might be searching for an excellent argument made in a debate, a sharpened pencil, or, knowing how users enter queries, I could very well be looking for a nice place for a picnic, or the rationale behind a traffic ticket's penalty.

So, I might expand it to a:

- `BooleanQuery`, joining:

  - `DisjunctionMaxQuery`: "multa", "fino", "sutil"
  - `DisjunctionMaxQuery`: "punta", "momento", "lugar"